# How to get better Graphics and Sound?

Tags: sound, graphics

When someone migrates from Windows to Linux, the first worries comes into mind that: *"Will I get the same graphics and sound quality as I get in Windows?"*  because generally motherboard's vendors don't provide any drivers for Linux.

I've been using Ubuntu since 2013. When I play audio loudly, the bass distorts and I don't have any real issues with my sound system. Graphics performance is also not so good as Windows. I am including my system's configurations with graphics and sound card details.

Can any experienced users suggest how to solve these issues? How can I improve the audio quality and get faster graphics? I have checked additional drivers found nothing.

Here are the hardware details:

```
pnath@Ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path        Device      Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         System Product Name (SKU)
/0                          bus            H61M-K
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor      Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G2020 @ 2.90GHz
/0/4/5                      memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                      memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                      memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/1                        memory         
/0/1/0                      memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/53                       memory         System Memory
/0/53/0                     memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/2                        memory         
/0/3                        memory         
/0/100                      bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
/0/100/2                    display        Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
/0/100/16                   communication  6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/1a                   bus            6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
/0/100/1b                   multimedia     6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                   bridge         6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
/0/100/1c.5                 bridge         6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
/0/100/1c.5/0   eth0        network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d                   bus            6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
/0/100/1f                   bridge         H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 storage        6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
/0/100/1f.3                 bus            6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/5            scsi0       storage        
/0/5/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVDRAM GH22NS70
/0/6            scsi1       storage        
/0/6/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           500GB ST500DM002-1BD14
/0/6/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1   volume         80GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/6/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2   volume         377GiB Extended partition
/0/6/0.0.0/2/5  /dev/sda5   volume         104GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/6/0.0.0/2/6  /dev/sda6   volume         104GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/6/0.0.0/2/7  /dev/sda7   volume         105GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/6/0.0.0/2/8  /dev/sda8   volume         61GiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/6/0.0.0/3    /dev/sda3   volume         7812MiB Linux swap volume
/1                          power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
pnath@Ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: ONLY EDITIONS ? NO ANSWER HAHAHA SO FUNNY PEOPLES

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly subjective question because as a general rule cheaper hardware = worse quality sound/graphics. The reason why this problem is worse on Linux is because the hardware vendor has written special drivers to get around hardware limitations and all Linux developers can do is guess at what they've done to fix problems.

You can't just compare Windows and Linux and say that one is better than the other. All that said, sound in Linux is an enigma. It always has been since the 90s. Multiple drivers and daemons for managing the sound has made for a giant mess.

One program you can run to give you a quick idea of what might be causing the distortion is the program `alsamixer` from the command line. It will show bar graphs of each channel's sound level. You can scroll right or left using the arrow keys and adjust sound levels up or down using up/down arrow.  If any of the channels are set to the max (in the red), then that may be where your distortion problem lies. Sometimes these sound channel levels don't show up in the GUI and you have to use a program like this to adjust the levels.  Like I said, sound is a mess because of multiple sound daemons (alsa vs. pulse vs. whatever other sound system is in fashion this year).

Most of these problems can be fixed and you're more likely to get a more helpful answer if you give more specific details about your problem instead of asking general questions about quality.